# How to store string in an array? - PHP

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

I'm trying to store a string in an array, but it doesn't save the array:

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    $username = $_POST["username"];
    $password = $_POST["password"];
    $users = array();
    $passes = array();
    /*if (isset($_SESSION['users'])) {
        $users = unserialize($_SESSION['users']);
    }
    if (isset($_SESSION['passes'])) {
        $passes = unserialize($_SESSION['passes']); 
    }*/

    if (isset($_POST['button'])) {
        $login_successful = false;
        for ($i = 0; $i < count($_SESSION['user']); $i++) {
            if ($username === $_SESSION['user'][$i] && $password === $_SESSION['pass'][$i]) {
                echo "<p style=\"font-family: Open Sans\">Logged in as " .$users[$i] ."</p>";
                $login_successful = true;
                break; // no need to continue the loop here, so we break out of it
            }
        }
        if (!$login_successful) {
            echo "<p style=\"font-family: Open Sans\">Login Failed</p>";
        }
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
        $users = array_push($users, $username);
        $passes = array_push($passes, $password);
        $_SESSION['user'] = serialize($users);
        $_SESSION['pass'] = serialize($passes);
        echo "Made your account successfully! <a href=\"index.html\">Go back to login</a>";
    }
    else if (isset($_POST['userlist'])) {
        $users = unserialize($_SESSION['users']);
        $passes = unserialize($_SESSION['passes']);

        for ($i = 0; $i < count($users); $i++) { 
            echo $user[$i];
            echo $passes[$i];
        }
    }
?>
```

It doesn't save the array, it changes it only for the current page it was called on and then the array goes back to nothing.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The premise of your question is wrong. When you conduct your research, try to find out how to store persistent values (hint: it's called a 'session').

Comment: PHP doesn't save any variables when it runs through. You're going to need to save the vars on the website, somewhere, either a file or a database. You have a lot of googling ahead of you.

Comment: use cookie or session, session is the better way i think

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have a huge misunderstanding of how PHP works. Each time a php script runs, it's like the first very first time it has ever ran. So, your array will be removed from memory when the script finishes.

However, if you want to carry data between requests, you can try a session.

```
session_start();//important

//YOUR EXISTING ARRAY
$array = array("element", "element 2", "element 3");

//ADD YOUR NEW ELEMENT TO THE ARRAY
$array = array_push( $array, "NEW ELEMENT" );

//store the new serialized (converted to string) array
$_SESSION['my_array'] = serialize( $array );

if ( isset($_SESSION['my_array']) ) {

    //grab the serialized (string version) of the array, and convert it back to an array

    $my_array = unserialize( $_SESSION['my_array'] ); //holds [0] => "el1", [1] => "el2"
}
```

Read more about sessions from the PHP manual.

You can also try cookies or storing the array into a database. Just know that cookies are stored on the user's computer, and sessions are stored on the server.

Comment: But how do I add a string to the array and make it stay there? I don't get that though...

Comment: I added some code that allows you to add a new element to the end of the array. Do you see why we need a session here?

Comment: Dang, it still won't work! I updated the code in the question to the exact code I'm using, can you still figure it out?

Comment: @user3504199 Are you getting errors? I'm still not sure exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is save the username and password in a session, so that when he/she registers they can login and it will store the pass and username. And no I'm not getting errors.

Comment: @user3504199 You're going about this all wrong. You should never store login credentials on the user's computer. You will need a database for this instead.

Answer (score -1):

you can use array_push like this : $user=array_push($user,$username);
That's all!

Answer (score -2):

let's do some improvement on Ryan Smith's solution to make it simpler

```
session_start();

$_SESSION['users'][] = 'Hello';

var_dump($_SESSION['users']);

// if you wanna use $users, 
/*
if(isset($_SESSION['users'])) {
    $users = unserialize($_SESSION['users']);
}
*/
```